# @XmlAnyElement is using the first element only

Tags: xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have an XML document with a list of Car ojects inside. In each car object there is a Person object as follows:

```
<Cars>
    <Car id=1>
        <Owner>
            <Name>
              John Blogs
            </name>
         </owner>
    </Car>
    <Car id=2>
        <Owner>
            <Name>
              Mary Murphy
            </name>
         </owner>
    </Car>
</Cars>
```

I would like to unmarshall this document as follows:

```
class Car{
    private String owner; 

    @XmlAnyElement(OwnerHandler.class)
    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
}
```

I have been told to implement the DomHandler interface and I have done that. The issue now is that my unmarshalled objects all use the name John Blogs - the code always finds and uses the first name. This is not ok if I have multipe Car objects.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this? Would @XmlPath work?

I'm tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Eclipse MOXy's @XmlPath attribute and it worked a treat.